# TFS advanced file history viewer

Tags: tfs

I would find usefull a tool for TFS that could answer these questions:

a. when this line of code has been checked in for first time?
b. what are the changsets wich have updated this method / block of code?
c. who modified this method?

I'm sure you got the point, my problem is that in the average my file's history is long, and sometimes is not easy to discover which changes have introduced regressions.

Is there a such tool ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of the information you request can be retrieved using `tf annotate` (or right-click on the item in VS and select `Annotate`): changeset and user per code change. Very practical for recent changes, but still difficult if you need to trace a certain change from "way back". You can use annotate from the history browser.

Comment: Thank you, Annotate is usefull and better than nothing, still I think there are spaces for improvements, expecially if you need to surf the history, I wonder why no company has fulfilled this gap.